# Why does implicit resolution not work accross type projections?

Tags: scala, implicit, type-level-computation

I'm trying to use a type class that establishes a (partial) order between types, where the types know their successor through a type member. But I'm facing the following implicit resolution problems:

```
trait T {
  type Next <: T
}

object T {
  implicit def succ[S <: T]: Succ[S,S#Next] = new Succ[S,S#Next]{}
}

trait T1 extends T {
  type Next = T2
}

trait T2 extends T {
  type Next = Nothing
}

trait Succ[X1 <: T, X2 <: T]

object Test {
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]](T.succ[T1])  //works

  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]](T.succ)      //fails
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]]              //fails
}
```

Here are the compiler errors:

```
Error:(23, 29) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [S <: test.objectinf.T]test.objectinf.Succ[S,S#Next]
 required: test.objectinf.Succ[test.objectinf.T1,test.objectinf.T2]
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]](T.succ)
                            ^
Error:(23, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : test.objectinf.Succ[S,S#Next]
 required: test.objectinf.Succ[test.objectinf.T1,test.objectinf.T2]
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]](T.succ)
                            ^
Error:(24, 13) could not find implicit value for parameter e: test.objectinf.Succ[test.objectinf.T1,test.objectinf.T2]
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]]
            ^
Error:(24, 13) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: test.objectinf.Succ[test.objectinf.T1,test.objectinf.T2])test.objectinf.Succ[test.objectinf.T1,test.objectinf.T2].
Unspecified value parameter e.
  implicitly[Succ[T1,T2]]
            ^
```

Comment: I don't have a chapter-and-verse answer, but this isn't too surprising to me—scalac takes every opportunity it can to forget refinements. `implicit def succ[N <: T, S <: T { type Next = N }]: Succ[S, N] = new Succ[S, N] {}` should work just fine.

Comment: @TravisBrown Your suggestion makes the code compile at least. Wanna turn it into an answer?